# Angular2 custom input - Token must be defined

Tags: typescript, angular

I have created a custom input component for html5 file uploads, but I get and error telling me that the Token must be defined. I'm not sure where to define it.

```
import { Component, Provider, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/common';

function makeProvider(type) {
  return new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => type),
      multi: true,
    });
}

@Component({
  selector: 'file-input',
  template: `
<div class="file-form">
    <div
    class="drop-zone"
    (dragover)="dragover = true"
    (dragleave)="dragover = false"
    (drop)="handleFiles($event); $event.preventDefault();"
    [ngClass]="{'dragover':dragover}"
    >
        Drop file here
    </div>
    <input type="file" (change)="handleFiles($event)" id="fileup"> <label for="fileup" class="button">Upload File</label>
    <br>
    <progress value="{{progress}}" max="100"></progress>
</div>
`,
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [makeProvider(FileInputComponent)],
  host: {
    '(fileChange)': 'onChange($event)',
  },
})
export class FileInputComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.progress = 0;
    this._value = '';
    this.onChange = () => {};
    this.onTouched = () => {};
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(v) {
    if (v !== this._value) {
      this._value = v;
      this.onChange(v);
    }
  }
  writeValue(value) {
    this._value = value;
    this.onChange(value);
  }
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    if (!(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)) {
      alert('html5 file upload not available!');
    }
    // Prevent file drops anywhere to load the file as current page
    window.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  }
  setValue(value) {
    this.image = value;
  }
  handleFiles(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    const files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', files[0]);
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // upload failed
    xhr.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
      console.warn('File upload failed');
    }, false);
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (e) => {
      if (e.lengthComputable) {
        this.progress = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
      }
    }, false);
    // uploadComplete
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      this.progress = 0;
      this.dragover = false;
    }, false);
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/api/files'); // identifier vom file ist `file`
    xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = (event) => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          const fileObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText || {});
          fileObj.type = files[0].type;
          this.onChange(fileObj);
        } else {
          console.warn(`File upload failed: ${xhr.responseText}`);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
}
```

> ViewWrappedException {_wrapperMessage: "Error in ./FormComponent class
>   FormComponent - inline template:34:3", ...
>   _context : DebugContext
>   _originalException : BaseException
>   _originalStack : "Error: Token must be defined!↵    at new BaseException...
>   _wrapperMessage : "Error in ./FormComponent class FormComponent - inline template:34:3"
>   _wrapperStack : "Error: Error in ./FormComponent class FormComponent - inline template:34:3↵    ... context

Comment: The error is happening in the `FormComponent` Maybe you could show the template of that component, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution

using the `makeProvider` function did not work

using

```
const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => FileInputComponent),
        multi: true,
    });
```

and adding

```
providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
```

solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` is now part of the `@angular/forms` module:

```
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: I tried to import it from there but it did not work, so i imported it the old way, I think this should not make a difference for the error that I get